# Missing border after zooming page

Tags: html, css

I have div's with input inside. This div's have 1px border. All it's good on normal state, but if we try zoom page to 70%-50% (ctrl-) - top border doesn't show, or top and bottom border if we zoom <50%. But some block don't missing borders. Why it's happend? Why some block missing border and some blocks doesn't? And how to fix it if this possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off Chrome 61, Firefox 52 ESR and IE 11 work with the following:

```
Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
```

Secondly you're talking about a single pixel at a *very* aggressive level of zooming. In order to validate even having this concern to begin with you should collect the zoom statistics from your visitors *first*. There are so many more problems of incredibly larger magnitude to be concerned with that I highly recommend considering your priorities for your own sake.